# Median-If With Month Criteria not working in LibreOffice

Tags: arrays, if-statement, criteria, median, libreoffice-calc

I have a simple spreadsheet like below, with columns:

- A: Timestamp
- B: A numerical result
- C: Time duration to compute above result

[image]

I want to compute the median value for duration for year 2019 March in cell I4. I used the following formula for it:

```
{=MEDIAN(IF((YEAR(A:A) = G1) * (MONTH(A:A) = 3), C:C))}
```

I expect value `48.5` should appear (median value b/w 41 and 56). But, it's showing an error `#VALUE!` when entered using Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Can someone point where the problem might be.

Comment: That does not look like Excel

Comment: Also "not working" is not a helpful description of the problem.

Comment: @ScottCraner Yeah, actually I'm using LibreOffice Calc, but I believe it's an equivalent of MS Excel, so the basic feature set should behave similarly. My bad, if there are differences in that also.

Comment: There are, in Excel you would simply need to confirm the formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode to make it an array formula.  I do not know the short cut in LibreOffice.

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner. It's indeed showing the `#VALUE!` error in the cell, using Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: Calc is stricter about the parameters of the IF() function than Excel - just specify a value for ELSE (third parameter). The "full" function will work the same in both programs. There are certainly differences, but if you know the features of both programs, then they are easy to avoid.